# eigenvalues of cycle graph and its complement graph

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

I am trying to find the eigenvalue of cycle graph and its complement. 
How to simplify.
Suppose  $\omega^{1}+\omega^{n-1}=2\cos (2\pi/n) $, then, $\omega^{\frac{n-1}{2}}+\omega^{\frac{n+1}{2}}=\ ?$ 
Is it true that $\omega^{1}+\omega^{n-1}=\omega^{\frac{n-1}{2}}+\omega^{\frac{n+1}{2}},$ where $\omega=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}}$?

Similarly, what is the value of $\omega^{0}+0+\omega^{2}+\omega^{3}+\cdots+\omega^{n-2}+0$.
 Both the adjacency matrices $C_n$ and its complement $\bar{C_{n}}$ gives circulant matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\omega$ is a primitive $n$th root of unity, $\omega^{k}$ and $\omega^{n-k}$ are conjugates. This means that $(1/2)(\omega^{k}+\omega^{n-k}) = \mathrm{Re}(\omega^{k}) = \cos{\frac{2\pi k}{n}}$ (and so $\omega^{\frac{n-1}{2}} + \omega^{\frac{n+1}{2}} = 2 \cos{\frac{(n-1)\pi}{n}}$).

Also, $\omega$ is a root of 
$$z^n -1 = (z-1)(z^{n-1} + \ldots + z+1),$$ so 
$$\omega^{n-1}+ \ldots + \omega+1 = 0,$$ therefore $$1 + 0 + \omega^{2} + \ldots + \omega^{n-2} + 0 = 0-\omega - \omega^{n-1} = -2\cos{\frac{2\pi}{n}}.$$

Comment: I am not satisfied with $2\cos\frac {n-1}{n}$ how can u miss pi. Can you please explain in detail.

Comment: Sorry, I am not convenienced. I think $2\cos2\pi/n$ is the correct one. But I am not able to prove.

Comment: I don't know why you'd think that $\omega^{k} + \omega^{n-k}$ would be the same for all $k$.  Think about them on the unit circle, and look what happens when you add them together.  Try it for $n = 5$, so $\omega = e^{2\pi/5}$.  Then $\omega + \omega^{4} = 2 \cos{2 \pi/5} \simeq .618$.  But $\omega^{2} + \omega^{3} = 2 \cos{4 \pi /5} \simeq -1.618$ (this is $\omega^{\frac{n-1}{2}} + \omega^{\frac{n+1}{2}} = 2 \cos{\frac{(n-1)\pi}{n}}$).  You can test this on a calculator or WolframAlpha.

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct, but i need show that $X$=$Y$ where $X$ and  $Y$ is a set containing an elements of $2\cos \frac{(n-1)\pi j}{n}$ and  $2\cos \frac{2\pi j}{n}$ where $j=0,1,2,...n-1$, respectively.<br> Thank you.